# PHP how to count the arrays values?

Tags: php

I'm trying to count all the values in the array and check if one value was entered and if so display a certain message for it and if there was more then one value entered display a different message for it.

How will I be able to this and where should I add it to my code?

Here is the code below.

```
if ($array == 1){
    echo $array . " has been entered";
} else {
    echo implode(", ", $array) . " have been entered";
}
```

Comment: note that the check is actually redundant in this case as implode with an array of size 1 will give the desired result also. Just replace the whole thing with 
echo implode(", ", $array) . " have been entered";
and skip the check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (count($array) == 1){
        echo $array[0] . " has been entered";
} else {
        echo implode(", ", $array) . " have been entered";
}
```

Comment: `sizeof()` also does the same thing, if you prefer writing `sizeof` instead of `count`.

Comment: `sizeof` is just an alias to `count`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (count($array)){
    echo implode(", ", $array) . " have been entered";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`count($array)` gives you number of elements in the array